# Error while installing Android Studio, no JDK found

Tags: jdk, android-studio

Tried other guides, no luck. Please assist

Got the following error

> No JDK found. Please validate either STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME
>   environment variable points to valid JDK installation.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have those environment variables set and working? Do you have permission/ownership to the folder `android-studio`/

Comment: I do not know how to set enviroment variables. I tried installing manually.

Comment: The latest version of Android Studio installs JDK 8 along with it by default in the same parent dsirectory as Android Studio.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this error I had to do the following:

### Install the Default JDK

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

### Set the JAVA_HOME Environment Variable

Get the JDK path here:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Edit the environments file

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

And add the `JAVA_HOME` path to the end of the file:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
```

Then reload the environment with

```
source /etc/environment
```

After that I was able to start the Android Studio setup without the error.

Source: [How To Install Java with Apt-Get on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to try to install it manually? The easiest way would be to use a repository as described here: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/install-android-studio-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer oracle-java8-set-default android-studio
```

Comment: While this is an alternative solution, this isn't really an answer to the question. I'm facing the same issue as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Before you execute studio.sh, you need to run the following from terminal (regardless whether using 32-bit or 64-bit OS).

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

Hope it helps. Cheers! ;)